# Subviews not appearing when UIScrollView is enabled

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

In my app, there is a subview that I use to implement auto-complete. It appears when a button is clicked. It works fine in normal case. But when I embed the whole lot into a UIScrollView, it doesn't work. Here is my code

```
_scrollArea=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1000)];
_scrollArea.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
_scrollArea.scrollEnabled=YES;
_scrollArea.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollArea];
_viewForAuto.hidden=false;
```

now here is the action call for the button click

```
- (IBAction)buttonOnFromPlace:(id)sender {
_selectedSlot=1;
_viewForAuto.hidden=false;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_viewForAuto];

[_autoFillData removeAllObjects];
[_theTable reloadData];}
```

UPDATE: The scroll itself is not working

UPDATE 2: Updated Code(got the sub view to the front, cant get the scroll to work)

```
_scrollArea.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 700);
_scrollArea.scrollEnabled=YES;
```

the action call

```
- (IBAction)buttonOnFromPlace:(id)sender {
_selectedSlot=1;
_viewForAuto.hidden=false;
[_scrollArea bringSubviewToFront:_viewForAuto];

[_autoFillData removeAllObjects];
[_theTable reloadData];}
```

Comment: what is the superview of _viewForAuto.

Comment: scrollArea is its super view

Comment: try this [_scrollArea bringSubviewToFront:_viewForAuto]; instead of [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_viewForAuto];

Comment: sorry, but the control is not flowing into the button's action

Comment: now i Got the control to flow to the action part by removing [self.view addSubview:_scrollArea];  but the modification you suggested didn't work

Comment: I think because of this line _scrollArea=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1000)]; scrolling is not work.Just comment this line and check scrolling is working or not. It is already in xib then no need to create object again.

Comment: This worked..Thanks a lot

Comment: well almost..I got the subview to appear now..the scroll still dosnt work

Comment: can you update your latest code .

Comment: Increase content size values and check once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85065/discussion-between-sidharth-j-dev-and-vishnuvardhan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want a scrolling for UIScrolllView,Our contentSize is must be greater then the frame size.If you want scrolling for you scroll view try this

```
_scrollArea.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollArea.frame.size.width,2*_scrollArea.frame.size.height);
```